# Seam Carving an image using Dijkstra algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Seam carving using Dijkstra's algorithm.

So far, I have converted the image to grayscale and using a 2D array, I've found out the energy function of the image. Now, to implement Dijkstra, I need to convert this 2D array into a graph and give a source and sink to the Dijsktra function.

I would like to know how to **change this 2D array into a graph**, as the 2D array, being a matrix of MxN, where M,N both can be very huge numbers, could give rise to possibly a huge number of graphs possible, and decide the sink for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert the image into a graph. All you have to do is use dynamic programming for computing seams and then finding the the seam with the minimum energy. To be more precise, to calculate S[i,j] (seam for pixel (i,j)):

1. For the first row, assign the energy value as seam value of the pixels S[1,j] = E[1,j]
2. For the next rows, propagate the minimum seam from the neighbors of the pixel downwards: S[i,j] = E[i,j] + min( S[i-1,j-1], S[i-1,j], S[i-1,j+1] )
3. Start from the element with minimum value in the last row of S and climb up by choosing neighbors with minimum seam values. Store each step.
4. The path you have stored is the seam with minimum energy.

I've also find a nice article with explains thoroughly the algorithm with MATLAB source code:

https://kirilllykov.github.io/blog/2013/06/06/seam-carving-algorithm/

Comment: I had implemented it via dynamic programming earlier. But I read somewhere that it also uses Dijkstra's algorithm, which usually works on graphs. So, there has to be some way through which we can obtain a graph.

Comment: The dynamic programming method mentioned here _is_ actually the Dijkstra algorithm. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Dynamic_programming_perspective) and of course [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283042/what-is-the-difference-between-dijkstras-method-and-dynamic-programming-when-fi). The `S` matrix mentioned in my answer is the _distance_ function and the iterative approach that we have taken to calculate it, is equivalent to Dijkstra's method of calculating distance of nodes.